# react-native-popup-menu : Error: (0 , _react2.createContext) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I have a listView. I want to open a popup menu when user long press on "name". But i am getting error of createContext.

```
  import {
     MenuContext,
     Menu,
     MenuOptions,
     MenuOption,
     MenuTrigger,
  } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

  render()
  {
   ...
   return(
         <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
        <MenuContext>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onLongPress = {this.openMenu}>
                  <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Ad_name}</Text>
                  <Menu ref={c => (this.menu = c)}>
                    <MenuTrigger text = "Select Action.." />
                    <MenuOptions>
                        <MenuOption onSelect = {() => this.onEditCampaignAction.bind(this, rowData.campaign_id)}>
                            {rowData.Status == '0' ?
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.SubmitButtonStyle}
                                    activeOpacity={.5}
                                    onPress={this.onEditCampaignAction.bind(this, rowData.campaign_id)}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon name='pencil' style={styles.icon} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                :
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.SubmitButtonStyle}
                                    activeOpacity={.5}
                                    onPress={this.onViewDetailsAction.bind(this, rowData.campaign_id)}>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon name='eye' style={styles.icon} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            }
                        </MenuOption>
                    </MenuOptions>
                </Menu>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </MenuContext>
     </View>
   );
 }
```

Comment: Do you really want that package. I would recommend [react-native-popover-menu](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-popover-menu) - for cross platform - and [react-native-popup-menu-android](https://github.com/Noitidart/react-native-popup-menu-android) - for android.

Comment: OK, will try react-native-popover-menu.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been fixed. react-native-popup-menu requires following versions:

React: 16.3.2
React-Native : 0.55.3

I upgraded versions of both and package installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are using incompatible version of RN. Downgrading to `0.12.x` will solve your problem.

See https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu#react-native-compatibility for more details

Comment: I am using these versions of RN: react-native-cli: 2.0.1,
react-native: 0.55.0

Comment: and which version of react do you have? if you have more information, add them to your github issue